# Error on installing pandoc 1.17.2-1

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`. Before I installed `pandoc 1.12.2.1-1build2` from `software center`. Today I downloaded `pandoc-1.17.2-1-amd64.deb` from [GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.17.2) and try to install it. But I got this error:

```
Unpacking pandoc (1.17.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive ~/Downloads/pandoc-1.17.2-1-amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', which is also in package pandoc-citeproc 0.2-3build1
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '~/Downloads/pandoc-1.17.2-1-amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
```

I also remove previous `pandoc` and try to install it's new version but it did not help. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the packages `pandoc-citeproc` and `pandoc` provide the same piece of software (conceptually) but they're packaged and distributed by unrelated people so they don't know about each other. That's why they have conflicting content but lack the `Conflicts` or `Replaces` flags that they should normally have in such a case.

To resolve the issue you need to remove the `pandoc-citeproc` package before you install the `pandoc` package.